# Undefined reference to _estack and _Min_Stack_Size in STM32 project with GCC

Tags: gcc, makefile, stm32

I'm encountering an issue while building my STM32 project using GCC. The error messages are as follows:

gcc -o Src/syscalls.o -c Src/syscalls.c
gcc -o main Src/main.o Src/syscalls.o Src/sysmem.o Src/uart.o
/usr/bin/ld: Src/sysmem.o: attention: réadressage sur « _estack » dans la section en lecture seule « .text »
/usr/bin/ld: Src/sysmem.o : dans la fonction « _sbrk » :
sysmem.c:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `_estack' /usr/bin/ld: sysmem.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to` _Min_Stack_Size'
/usr/bin/ld: attention: création de DT_TEXTREL dans un PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:13 : main] Erreur 1

I am facing linker errors during the compilation of my STM32 project. It seems to be related to the symbols _estack and _Min_Stack_Size in the file sysmem.c. The linker is unable to find these references, resulting in a failed build.

Undefined Reference to _estack: The linker reports an undefined reference to the symbol _estack in the section .text while processing the file sysmem.c during the _sbrk function.

Undefined Reference to _Min_Stack_Size: Additionally, there is an undefined reference to the symbol _Min_Stack_Size in the same file.

I am seeking guidance on how to resolve these linker errors and successfully build my STM32 project. Any assistance or insights into what might be causing these issues would be greatly appreciated.

- Project uses GCC as the compiler.
- STM32 microcontroller is being used.
- The complete Makefile is available for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Those symbols are usually defined in the **linker script"*. You probably do not have one or you wrote an invalid one.

It is an example beginning of the linker script (defining those symbols):

```
/* Entry Point */
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)

/* Highest address of the user mode stack */
_estack = ORIGIN(RAM_START) + 96K;    /* end of RAM */
/* Generate a link error if heap and stack don't fit into RAM */
_Min_Heap_Size = 0x200;      /* required amount of heap  */
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x400; /* required amount of stack */
```

Of course `RAM_START` is memory area definition and `Reset_Handler` is the symbol from one of the source files defining the program entry point.

I would strongly advice to do not try to write DIY makefiles if you do not have a very deep knowledge of the toolchain and target hardware. Stick to STM32CubeIDE which will generate those for you.